# Instalação do PyDev no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando instalar o pydev no Eclipse, porém não aparece nenhuma versão para ser instalada conforme pode ser visto abaixo:

O que devo fazer para instalar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já fez todos os passos descritos na instalação (http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)?

Comment: Para a instalação via URL, sim, já. Só não havia tentado via zip. Só deu certo por essa alternativa. Pelo visto via URL parece não funcionar mais, pois no manual orienta a utilizar a URL para o qual o http://www.pydev.org/updates/ redireciona, que é https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/6.4.4. E não funcionou.